# Asp.net core 3.1. I'm trying to make an web application that forces users to cheange their password if a specific flag in tha DB is set to true

Tags: asp.net-core

I tried to make some sort of middleware which checks if the user must change his password, and then, if he does, to redirect him to specific page.

The middleware service looks like this:

```
private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public MustChangePassword(RequestDelegate next/*, UserManager<User> userManager*/)
    {
        _next = next;
                
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserManager<User> userManager)
    {   
        var crtUser = await userManager.GetUserAsync(context.User);

        if (crtUser != null) 
        {
            if (crtUser.MustChangePassword != null) 
            {
                if ((bool)crtUser.MustChangePassword) 
                {
                    string requestURL = context.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower();
                    if (!(requestURL.Contains("MustChangePassword") || requestURL.Contains("ResetPassword")))
                    {
                        var returnUrl = context.Request.Path.Value == "/" ? "" : "?returnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path.Value);

                        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/MustChangePassword"+returnUrl ,true);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            await _next(context).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }
 
    }
}
public static class MustChangePasswordMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMustChangePassword(
        this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MustChangePassword>();
    }
}
```

I added the following line of code in the Configure from Stratup.cs method:

```
app.UseMustChangePassword();
```

I did some debuging and found out that the **redirect** works in a way, but after the code execution reaches the right method

```
public IActionResult MustChangePassword() 
    {
        
        return View();
    }
```

It goes back on the original path. I want to redirect the user on that View and then to force him to stay there.

Comment: Your middleware is invoked for _every_ request, including the change-password-request.

Comment: I know, I will solve this problem as soon as I solve the redirect problem

Comment: I think it is the source of your redirect problem.